# Pointwise Convergence and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I am having trouble knowing how to start a homework problem. If anybody could give me the first step, or lead me through a different but similar example, that would be greatly appreciated. The problem is below:

Suppose $f_n$:X $\rightarrow$ Y is a sequence of functions such that there is a number L > 0 so that for all n:

$\forall$ x,y in X : $d_Y$(f(x), f(y)) $\le$ L$d_X$(x, y)

Suppose that $f_n$ converges pointwise to a function f: X$\rightarrow$Y. Show that f is continuous.

What I have so far: 
WTS that for every sequence ($x_n$) in X which converges to p in X, lim f($x_n$) = f(p) in Y.
Since $f_n$ converges pointwise, we know that there for all x in X and all positive $\epsilon$, there exists some N such that $d_Y$($f_n$(x), f(x)) < $\epsilon$ for all n > N. From here, I feel I need to use the statement $d_Y$(f(x), f(y)) $\le$ L$d_X$(x, y) somehow, but I don't know what to do since it has two variables and my definitions only use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $L$ does not depend neither on $n$ nor on $x$ and $y$, we can actually show that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz. You got the idea, here is a way to formalize it:

> If $(S,d)$ is a metric space and $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$, $(b_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ are two sequences such that $d(a_n,a)\to 0$ and $d(b_n,b)\to 0$, then $d(a_n,b_n)\to d(a,b)$.

To see that, use the triangle inequality 
$d(a_n,b_n)-d(a,b)\leqslant d(a_n,a)+d(a,b)+d(b,b_n)-d(a,b)=d(a_n,a)+d(b_n,b)$
and similarly for reverse inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My class did not cover "L-Lipschitz", and I do not quite understand where the L goes using this description. Also, how would I connect the triangle equality for sequences to functions of sequences?

Comment: By $L$-Lipschitz, I mean that we can prove that $d_Y(f(x),f(y))\leqslant L\cdot d_X(x,y)$ for any $x$ and $y$.  We use this with $a_n:=f_n(x)$ and $b_n:=f_n(y)$ for fixed $x$ and $y$.